# Добавление файлов в папку Assets

Tags: android, android-studio, файлы, android-assets

Для хранения файлов решил воспользоваться папкой Assets. В нее вручную закинул файл   ten_ways. Однако почему-то когда вывожу список файлов через

```
AssetManager manager = getApplicationContext().getAssets();
        try {
            String[] files = manager.list("");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),files[0],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Ничего не выводится. То есть почему-то не находит ничего. В чем проблема?

Вот структура каталогов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю Вы забыли вызвать метод show у объекта Toast.